# Symfony - get access to the method from another file in controller

Tags: php, symfony, code-injection

I am using symfony 3 and trying to get access to the class I declared in

> src/AppBundle/Service/ApiEngine.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;


use DateTime;

class ApiEngine {

    private $api_handler;

    public function __construct($username, bool $repos) {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $request = 'https://api.github.com/users/' . $username;
        $request .= ($repos) ?  '/repos' : "";
        $res = $client->request('GET', $request);

        $this->api_handler = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    }

    public function getProfileData() {
        return [ /*some data*/ ];
    }
}
```

I declared this file in

> config/service.yml

```
service:
  *
  *
  *
  api:
      class: AppBundle\Service\ApiEngine
      arguments: ["@username", "@repos"]
```

In controller I am trying to use some of the ApiEngine methods like this:

> src/AppBundle/Controller/GitApiController.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route; use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class GitApiController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route("/{username}", name ="gitapi", defaults={"username": "symfony"})
     */
    public function gitApiAction($username) {
        $api = $this->get('api')->__construct($username, false)->getProfileData();

        return $this->render('gitapi/index.html.twig', $api);
    } }
```

But it gives me this error:

> (1/1) ServiceNotFoundException The service "api" has a dependency on a
>   non-existent service "username".

Comment: what is your "username" you pass in the service ?

Comment: in service file the arguments might be : ["@another_service_name", "plain_value", "%parameter_name%"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to change your class into this for example:

```
private function __construct($username, bool $repos) {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $request = 'https://api.github.com/users/' . $username;
        $request .= ($repos) ?  '/repos' : "";
        $res = $client->request('GET', $request);

        $this->api_handler = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    }

public static function createApiEngine($username, bool $repos) 
{
    return new self($username, $bool);
}
```

After inside your controller you can do this:

```
$api = ApiEngine::createApiEngine($username, false);
$api->getProfileData();
```

Into your controller you need to insert a `use` for `ApiEngine`, in this use case you don't need dependency injection so inside your `services.yml` remove arguments please